# How do I prevent the command line arguments of the run configuration for my GWT project from being overwritten?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, run-configuration

I have a multi-module GWT project that I am trying to debug using SuperDevMode (or maybe the new name is GWT Dev Mode with Jetty) in Eclipse.

I am using:

- Mars .2 (Version 4.5.2)
- GWT 2.7 SDK (although 2.8.1 is also installed)
- GWT Eclipse Plugin 3.0.0
- Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT 1.3.0
- gwt-maven-plugin version 1.0-rc-8

In the past, occasionally, when running the GWT Dev Mode, the run would fail with the following message:

```
Runing CodeServer with parameters: [-noprecompile, -port, 9876, -sourceLevel,
1.7, -bindAddress, 127.0.0.1, -launcherDir,
/Users/SomeUser/Documents/customers/SomeCustomer/dev/workspace/FolderName/target/NAME-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT,
-logLevel, INFO, ca.example.Name, .module]
Invalid module name: '.module'
Google Web Toolkit 2.7.0
```

(Yes, it does say "runing", not "running", I just noticed that). Note that I changed some of the path and class names, but those changes shouldn't be significant.

I have addressed this problem by editing the Run Configuration. It turns out that an additional command line argument was added to the end,  '.module'. When I remove that argument, I can debug.

But, that argument keeps coming back. Recently, it comes back every time I try to debug the application using Run As -> GWT Dev Mode with Jetty.

I have tried using the gwt:devmode maven goal, and it works OK every time so far.

I also have tried saving a local copy of the run configuration. The saved configuration looks OK, but when I try to run it, '.module' is added prior to the debug session being started and I get the same error.

I guess I could just start using gwt:devmode to start my debug sessions, but the debug environment is slightly different so I would like to be able to continue using GWT Dev Mode with Jetty.

Has anybody come across this phantom '.module' insert and figured out how to get Eclipse to stop doing it?

Comment: This can happen, if the module descriptor is renamed. First, run you project, then rename the module descriptor and then run again. In this case you see the reference to the old module descriptor and the new reference. Normally, after removing the old reference it should work.

Comment: As far as I know, I'm not changing the module descriptor. My workflow is, try to debug, get the error, remove '.module' from the run configuration parameters, debug successfully. Then the next time I try to debug (with no changes that I'm aware of), I get the error again (and again, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Quick Fix: From eclipse you can save a run configuration as an xml file and commit it in your repo, so all the devs can have the correct config at hand.

Smells like there is some folder or file that trick Eclipse into thinking that it is a .gwt.xml module and add it to the list of the available modules.

Comment: I've tried saving the configuration. The resulting file looks correct, but when I open it in eclipse and try to "run" it, I get the same error and the configuration editor shows that eclipse has already added '.module'. It appears that sometime between opening the configuration file and running or displaying it, Eclipse (or the GWT plugin or something) is processing the configuration's contents and adding the '.module.'. I agree with your hypothesis regarding how it smells. I'd like to think it's due to some error I have in my project set up rather than with the plugins.

Comment: We need more info to actually help. I don't know how much of your project you can share but the content of the eclipse run file (should be some xml) and/or project files/folder structure would help giving you a better feedback,

Comment: I don't think I'll be able to share much of the project. That said I'm testing a crazy hypothesis that might provide some insight and will provide an update on how it works out.

Comment: I have project that sometimes illustrates the problem. It is the project that we are using as our template when starting a new GWT project or "mavenizing" an existing GWT project. Since it only sometimes illustrates the problem, I hesitate to publish it, as it may be a waste of time for you to review it. That said, I have come up with a kludge answer that seems to make the problem mostly go away. I don't know why, but that's good enough for now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kludge answer that makes the problem go away for us, most of the time, so far. I suspect the correct answer is that our project structure is slightly wonky. As we learn more about GWT and the standard way to set up maven projects, we will likely figure out the proper answer or re-structure our projects so that we no longer have this problem.

That said, the problem seems to go away when we re-add the module definition file.

By that, I mean ...

Based on some random Googling, when we convert a GWT project to maven, we have been moving the module definition file from

`packagename/modulename.gwt.xml`

to

`src/main/module.gwt.xml`.

Doing so seems to cause the above problems.

To address the issue, I copied

`src/main/module.gwt.xml`

back to

`packagename/modulename.gwt.xml`

and the problem goes away, except for, sometimes, the very first time we attempt to run the project in "GWT development mode with Jetty". And yes, I know that we now have two copies of the file and that seems just wrong.

I don't know why it happens and thought that the module definition should be in src/main/module.gwt.xml. But it works, so I can live with it for now.